# Xubuntu 20.04 xfce4 Weather Plugin 0.10.1 = No Data

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel, weather

Weather worked fine for a few months, now = no Data.

Tried: Changing location to another and changed back = no joy. Deleted `/.config/xfce4/panel/weather-14.rc`. The app made another `.rc` file but still no joy.

The same thing has happened on my Linux Mint 20.04/Xfce computer.

Comment: As the same thing happened on a second computer, I'd check to ensure the weather data providing service/server is still there, still responding, and hasn't changed anything like their API.

Comment: Seems to be a bug with changed API - https://gitlab.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-weather-plugin/-/issues/27

Comment: FYI:  there is mention on the topic right now (#xubuntu-devel on irc)  *groovy* & *focal*   the best place to get it fixed is most likely a bug report, so a *developer* is made aware of it, and gets prompted to start the SRU process...  The API cause (grace period ending on change) can be read at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2458828  or item 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Cinnamon 19. It updated xfce so I could get any fixed packaged version of the weather update. So I downloaded the code and build it like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274259/xfce4-weather-plugin-for-xubuntu-18-04-stopped-working)

In case you get stuck, I would pass the deb package I've created for you to use.

Comment: Thanks. I built the package you listed "here". And it works.

Comment: Well. if my answer helped you could accept it...

Comment: MX Linux debs at https://askubuntu.com/a/1321710/25639