# xfce4 weather plugin compile error

Tags: xubuntu, compiling, plugins, weather

I am working for a non-profit that is provisioning donated machines running xfce4.  The weather plugin has been integral (nice feature) for our customers.  I am trying to compile from source using build-debs and git according to this link:

[XFCE4 Weather Plugin stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274259/xfce4-weather-plugin-for-xubuntu-18-04-20-04-stopped-working)

I am currently running xubuntu 20.04 in a virtualbox vm trying to compile it to fix our image we will distribute,  but I can't get cut'n paste from guest to host working.  I'll have to 'wing it'.  I get config.status error executing default-l commands:

> ./config.status: line 2127: po/Makefile: Permission denied and
> config.status: executing po/stamp-it commands
> ./config.status: 2145: po/Makefile: permission denied
> compilations stops.

I have looked at the code and is has something to do with changing file permissions to executable for a couple of files referenced as variables.  (I have not compiled anything in like ah... forever.  So I am behind the curve.  I welcome your assistance.

Regards

Edit for steeldriver:

$ ls -ld po/{,Makefile}
drwxrwxr-x 2 auditer auditer  4096 Mar  6 16:56 po/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    10208 Mar  5 22:55 po/Makefile

```
       libweather_la-weather.lo
```

weather.c:2305:1: fatal error: opening dependency file .deps/libweather_la-weather.Tpo: Permission denied
2305 | XFCE_PANEL_PLUGIN_REGISTER(weather_construct)
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld po/{,Makefile}` ?

Comment: Hi steeldriver,  I was able to compile w/o errors after changing the owner of po/Makefile to current user :), but I ran into another error.  weather.c:23-5:1 fatal error: opening dependency file .deps/libweather_laweather.Tpo Permission denied.  2305 XFCE_PANEL_PLUGIN_REGISTER(weather_construct).  There is not .deps folder with that file anywhere.

Comment: It sounds like some of the steps were performed as root / with sudo when they should have been performed as your ordinary user - only the final `make install` should be executed as root.

Comment: Yes I cleared up the ownership issue.  now I have added a new issue...  Make failed.  I have detailed it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother compiling and grab this one from MX Linux.
[http://mxrepo.com/mx/repo/pool/main/x/xfce4-weather-plugin/xfce4-weather-plugin_0.10.2-1~mx17_amd64.deb](http://mxrepo.com/mx/repo/pool/main/x/xfce4-weather-plugin/xfce4-weather-plugin_0.10.2-1%7Emx17_amd64.deb)

Comment: Yeah I'll give that a shot see how it works.  still would lke to know why I got a permission denied error for folder and file that does not exist..

Answer (score 3):

Did you accidentally run one of the commands as root? Also, did you run a failed `make` command?

Whenever you start over, you should run `make clean` or `sudo make clean` if you need to. However, if you ran `./audogen.sh` as root or if the clean commands don't help, then it would be best to start over.

First, `cd` out of the `xfce4-weather-plugin` directory and then move it out of the way:

```
cd ..
mv xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-weather-plugin-initial
```

Now, download the files:

```
git clone https://gitlab.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-weather-plugin.git
```

cd into the directory, edit your `./autogen.sh` file and autogenerate your make files:

```
cd xfce4-weather-plugin
sed -i 's/4.14.0/4.12.0/' ./autogen.sh
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

If the command is a success, it will display a message that it is now okay to run `make`. If you get an error (probably to install a missing package), follow the suggested fix and then run `./autogen.sh` again. Repeat this process until you reach success.

Finally, finish the installation with `make` and `sudo make install`

```
make
sudo make install
```

If you need to start over, you should run `make clean` or `sudo make clean` before you begin again.

Comment: Hi mchid,  Yeah I followed the directions from the link I referenced in my original post.  And yes I did run make as super user.  but then I ran sudo make clean, make clean.  fixed po/Makefiles perms.  still ran into an error that I referenced above. tx

Comment: @TerenceGolightly Yes, this is why I suggest to just start over and clone a new directory to avoid those problems.

Comment: okay tx mchid.  I will give that  a try tomorrow.  Next is integrating it into our image.

Comment: @TerenceGolightly Yeah, if a deb package is available from MX it's probably not needed though. I just figured it would be good to know for future reference. Hopefully they'll fix that bug and update to 10.2.1 soon. Come to think of it, that might be a good reason to use `/usr` so that the updated version would overwrite it when it's no longer needed. I guess I stand corrected.

Comment: `git clean -dfx` would avoid the need to clone again, I think

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks. That's good to know. Although, I did find at least [one report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976300/git-clean-dfx-does-not-remove-ignored-directory) of this not working correctly.